# Target multiple specific ID, Anchor hash Elements - for jQuery onclick function

Tags: jquery

Here's the code I am using which targets all same-page `#` links.

```
$('a[href*=\\#]').on('click', function(event){     

// code here

});
```

But one out of the three elements on my page does not need this on click function.

The two I'm looking to specify are `#about-us` and `#top`

I've tried targeting them specifically, and with a comma separator, such as

```
$('$about-us,#top').on('click', function(event){
```

But this is not correct.

How do I modify this code to target specific links (or `id`s)?

Comment: what about giving a common class name to all the elements you want to click? and use it like ```$('.commonClass').on('click', function(event){````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, simply stack those attribute selectors:

```
$("a[href='#about-us'], a[href='#top']").on('click', function(event){
```

Here's a demo

```js
$("a[href='#about-us'], a[href='#top']").on('click', function(event){  

    event.preventDefault();
    console.log( this.hash );

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
<li><a href="#about-us">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:;">Contact (will not log)</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you want an `if / else`... - you can explore ***[more magic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)***

```js
// Target all hash anchors...
$("a[href^='#']").on('click', function(event){  

    event.preventDefault();
    var hash = this.hash.substr(1); // remove "#"

    if(hash && hash.match(/^(about-us|top)$/)) {
      console.log("MATCHES "+ hash);
    } else {
       console.log("This anchor is not in the matching group!");
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
<li><a href="#home">STRANGE UP ARROW ICON</a></li>
<li><a href="#about-us">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Simple when you think about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in the following way....

```
    $('#id1, #id2').on('click', some_function);
```

Comment: This will only work for id's but if you want to detect links then the other answer is the solution for that